# How can I analyse a Sqlite query execution?

Tags: sql, sqlite, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have a Sqlite database which I want to check the indexes are correct.  MS SQL Analyser is great at breaking down the query execution and utilised indexes.

Is there a similar tool for Sqlite?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I know of no pretty graphical tools, but all of the information you seek is available from the `EXPLAIN` keyword.

Consider this database:

```
sqlite> create table users (name, email);
sqlite> create index user_names on users (name);
```

A query predicated on `email` will not use an index:

```
sqlite> explain select * from users where email='foo';
```

| addr | opcode | p1 | p2 | p3 | p4 | p5 | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Trace | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 1 | String8 | 0 | 1 | 0 | foo | 00 |  |
| 2 | Goto | 0 | 13 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 3 | OpenRead | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 00 |  |
| 4 | Rewind | 0 | 11 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 5 | Column | 0 | 1 | 2 |  | 00 |  |
| 6 | Ne | 1 | 10 | 2 | collseq(BINARY) | 6a |  |
| 7 | Column | 0 | 0 | 4 |  | 00 |  |
| 8 | Column | 0 | 1 | 5 |  | 00 |  |
| 9 | ResultRow | 4 | 2 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 10 | Next | 0 | 5 | 0 |  | 01 |  |
| 11 | Close | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 12 | Halt | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 13 | Transaction | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 14 | VerifyCookie | 0 | 5 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 15 | TableLock | 0 | 2 | 0 | users | 00 |  |
| 16 | Goto | 0 | 3 | 0 |  | 00 |  |

Whereas a query predicated on name will use the `user_names` index:

```
sqlite> explain select * from users where name='foo';
```

| addr | opcode | p1 | p2 | p3 | p4 | p5 | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Trace | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 1 | String8 | 0 | 1 | 0 | foo | 00 |  |
| 2 | Goto | 0 | 18 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 3 | OpenRead | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 00 |  |
| 4 | OpenRead | 1 | 3 | 0 | keyinfo(1,BINARY) | 00 |  |
| 5 | IsNull | 1 | 15 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 6 | Affinity | 1 | 1 | 0 | bb | 00 |  |
| 7 | SeekGe | 1 | 15 | 1 | 1 | 00 |  |
| 8 | IdxGE | 1 | 15 | 1 | 1 | 01 |  |
| 9 | IdxRowid | 1 | 2 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 10 | Seek | 0 | 2 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 11 | Column | 1 | 0 | 3 |  | 00 |  |
| 12 | Column | 0 | 1 | 4 |  | 00 |  |
| 13 | ResultRow | 3 | 2 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 14 | Next | 1 | 8 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 15 | Close | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 16 | Close | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 17 | Halt | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 18 | Transaction | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 19 | VerifyCookie | 0 | 5 | 0 |  | 00 |  |
| 20 | TableLock | 0 | 2 | 0 | users | 00 |  |
| 21 | Goto | 0 | 3 | 0 |  | 00 |  |

Using `EXPLAIN` does require coming to grips with SQLite's virtual machine, VDBE:

http://www.sqlite.org/opcode.html

But this is not as hard as it looks, and gives you the complete story about your query.

Comment: `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` will give info about index use without the VM instructions.

Comment: You can also improve the output format, if desired, by enabling the .explain option in the command line: ".explain ON|OFF        Turn output mode suitable for EXPLAIN on or off."

Comment: The above link is outdated, look here for information about the virtual machine: http://www.sqlite.org/opcode.html

Answer (score 30):

As outis said:

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM FOO
```

Does the trick with a more readable output, if like me you're simply using it to ensure you're hitting your indexes (indices?)

Comment: There is a nice explanation of the output of this command here: https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html

Answer (score 9):

There's this nice graphical tool

https://github.com/asutherland/grok-sqlite-explain

Here's example of output:

[image: Example output of explain]

And associated blogpost:
http://www.visophyte.org/blog/2010/04/06/performance-annotated-sqlite-explaination-visualizations-using-systemtap/