# Query plan For Sqlite

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite, sql-execution-plan

Does Sqlite create a "query plan" for the complex queries? (I know mysql creates one and chooses the best of different available combination to execute the query). Is there any way i can get [last_query_cost](http://cherry.world.edoors.com/CAMxVWbgEVUY) as i usually get in mysql. i am trying to migrate from mysql to sqlite due to some resource requirement for my application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I analyse a Sqlite query execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454188/how-can-i-analyse-a-sqlite-query-execution)

Comment: its not the question is whether sqllite really support query estimator/query plan optimizer and have variable like last_query_cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite supports the [EXPLAIN keyword](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html), like MySQL, but syntax is slightly different:

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT col FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. is there anything equivalent to last_query_cost(works for mysql) in sqlite?

Comment: @user530928: Not that I can see in the documentation.  SQLite doesn't have as many features as MySQL, because it's primary intended as an embedded database -- smaller footprint.